# Shape detection with cv2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect shapes within pixels using cv2. Currently using examples such as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-shapes-in-images-in-python-using-opencv/ however this will only define each pixel, rather than identifying from the larger outset. I've attempted to add blur however that causes cv2 to identify the shapes as circles as opposed to squares.

Example images:
[image]
[image]

What would the best way to process these? Ideally fro the above two images, there's 3 distinct square patterns.

Comment: Use morphology open and close with a square kernel.

Comment: @ext32 worked this out?

Comment: @JeruLuke for the most part yes, though just quite a bit of fine-tuning and it's not overly great due to the amount of random pixels in each image